# Justification of the given proof on elementary set theory

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

A,B,C are sets, I proved the following partially and wanted to correct and better the way I approach to "Proofs" in Set theory with Your help:
Given that

`Given that 
(A union B)is subset of (A union C)
and
(A intersection B) is subset of (A intersection C)
Prove that B is subset of C.
The way I proved it partially as follows:
(A union B)is subset of (A union C)= (A union B)intersection (A union C)=(A union B)
By Distributive property, I get:
=(A intersection(A union C)) union (B intersection(A union C))=(A union B)
=((A intersection A) union (A intersection C)) union (B intersection(A union C))
=(A union B)
=(A union (A intersection C)) union (B intersection(A union C))=(A union B)
=(A) union ((B intersection A) union (B intersection C))=(A union B)
I rewrite the last equation so that it would be clear how I eliminate A-s from both sides:
= A u [(BnA) u (BnC)] = A u B
=> [(BnA) u (BnC)] = B
=> (BnC) = B because u-sign represents union and "or" ,therefore either (BnA) or (BnC) equals to B`

Is my reasoning correct? Am I allowed to make such conclusions?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume x in B.

Case 1.  x not in A.
Since x in A u B subset A u C, x in A u C.
As x not in A, x in C.

Case 2.  x in A.
Since x in A n B subset A n C subset C, x in C.